# What pattern does SLF4J use?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection

The design of SLF4J really excited me. I mean the way it introduces the implementing component. In the *LoggerFactory*, it imports *org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder*, a class in its namespace but that doesn't exist in its jar file. The implementation (like logback) jar just includes the class and it's done. The classloader will do the binding work for you.

This makes the implementing component plugable / drop-in-able, zero configuration, your code only depend on SLF4J.

I want to know, does this approach have an orthodox name? Or any related design patterns? I want to learn more about it.

Comment: I don't think there's really a name for this technique, I'm afraid. In the world of procedural software it's so ubiquitous that I suspect nobody really every thought it needed a name. Object oriented languages are easier to configure at run time than procedural languages (due to the emphasis on virtual dispatch) so design pattern catalogues generally concentrate on technique for that.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a definite name for this but in the context of Java I've heard the term "Service Loader" used most for this pattern/mechanism. You program against an API at and provide an implementation of that service at runtime. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a combination of patterns and well-engineered implementation.

The first pattern that comes to mind is [Dependency Inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle#Dependency_inversion_pattern). By defining interfaces, Slf4j defers implementation until runtime. Another pattern is [delegation pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern), which allows the dependency inversion to provide good traction.

The implementation uses a service loader, as @Kapep mentioned, to perform the dependency injection.